# dynamically add and remove panels PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, user-interface, primefaces

How would you go about dynamically adding panels in primefaces?

The goal is to have a button to add panels. Removing panels is easy to with the closeable option in the following code:

```
<p:panel id="panel1" header="Panel 1" style="width : 150px;" toggleable="true" closable="true" toggleSpeed="500" closeSpeed="500"> Move and Resize ME!</p:panel>
```

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that you have a panelgrid to hold the panels, a simple jsf fragment would be

```
<p:panelGrid id="myPanelGrid" columns="1">
</p:panelGrid>

<h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Add Panel" actionListener="#{bean.addPanel}" update=":myPanelGrid" />
</h:form>
```

In your backing bean, an addPanel method needed for dynamically adding panels

```
public void addPanel(ActionEvent event) {
    UIComponent component = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("myPanelGrid");
    if (component != null) {
        Panel p = new Panel();
        p.setClosable(true);
        p.setHeader("Test");
        p.setVisible(true);
        component.getChildren().add(p);
    }
}
```

This method will find your holder panelgrid component by its id, add a new org.primefaces.component.panel.Panel and set a few fields and add it to the parent component.

The update=":myPanelGrid" property of your commandButton will inform the panelGrid to update itself with the new data.

Answer (score 1):

Simply I would nest my `<p:panel` in a `<h:panelGroup` with a `rendered` attribute this way :

```
<h:panelGroup id="myPanelGroup">
    <p:panel rendered="#{myBean.renderPanel}">
        <span>Content</span>
    </p:panel>
</h:panelGroup>
<p:commandButton action="#{myBean.showPanel()}" update="myPanelGroup"
    value="Show Panel" />
<p:commandButton action="#{myBean.hidePanel()}" update="myPanelGroup"
    value="Hide Panel" />
```

The Bean :

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean {

    private boolean renderPanel;

    public void showPanel() {
        this.renderPanel = true;
    }

    public void hidePanel() {
        this.renderPanel = false;
    }

    // Getter for renderPanel
}
```

**Note** : It would be even better to avoid using `@ViewScoped` here depending on your needs, you could bind `renderPanel` in a form (eg a checkbox)